# Can I specify the DataType to be returned on a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, function

Is there a way to create a function that only returns strings? For context, I was trying to create the function attached as a screenshot, with the aim of concatenating two strings and returning another string. However, the function also worked on numbers, as it added them. In some cases, I would only want the function to work on a particular data type. Is this possible?

[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clovv.png)

```
function concatenate(a,b) {
  return (a+b);
}
```

Comment: So convert the arguments to the data type you want. Or add validation that the types are what you want.

Comment: Do not post an image of code. We can not copy and paste text from an image.

Comment: convert your function params to strings

Comment: Short answer is yes, that is easy enough to do. Would like to see the question updated with the code (not a link to an image) and anything you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

So you either convert them the types you want

```js
function example (a, b) {
  return a.toString() + b.toString();
}
console.log(example("foo", "bar"));
console.log(example(1, 2));
```

Or you do validation on the types

```js
function example (a, b) {
  if (typeof a !== "string" || typeof b !== "string" ) {
    throw new Error("Strings expected");
  }
  return a + b;
}
console.log(example("foo", "bar"));
console.log(example(1, 2));
```

If you really care about string vs String

```
if (
  !(typeof a === 'string' || a instanceof String) || 
  !(typeof b === 'string' || b instanceof String)) {
  throw new Error("Strings expected");
}
```

Comment: Utilizing `String` as typecast function instead of the `toString` method might be the better choice  since the latter fails e.g. for the `undefined` and the `null` value or for strange objects like `Object.create(null)` ... `return String(a) + String(b);`

Comment: And the 2nd approach will throw an Error for any valid argument which is a `String` objects. Thus the type detection should not only target (primitive) string values.

Comment: I think of protecting against the possible use of the use of the String constructor (ie `new String('happy')`) as a corner case -- although more protection is arguably always better. **Would this be the best way to handle that eventuality?: `const isString = str => str && typeof str == "string" || Object.getPrototypeOf(str).constructor.name == "String";`** (It's a shame to have to dig this deeply into the protype just to safely use a string argument, but maybe this is how the robust, big-name libraries handle string validation.)

Comment: All I can say if you want this level of security, move to TypeScript.

Comment: *"All I can say if you want this level of security, move to TypeScript"* ... In the 1st case `example` is a generically implemented function which consumes twice `any` type; Thus one would not benefit from a TypeScript environment. The latter was helpful though for the 2nd `example` implementation.

Comment: @Cat ... a generic String value/type detection might be closer to ... `const isString = value => (/\[object\s+String\]/).test(Object.prototype.toString.call(value));`

Answer (score 0):

Generic function can be created accepting the type and it can return function making all validations which can be used to perform action.

```
function GenericConcat(typeA,typeB) {
  return (a,b) => {
    if (typeof a == typeA && typeof b == typeB ) {
      return a + b;
    }
    throw new Error("Parameter type expected: "+ typeA +"-"+ typeB);
  }
}
```

```
stringConcate = GenericConcat("string","string");
stringConcate("a","b"); //ab
stringConcate("a",1)    //Error: Parameter type expected: string-string

numberConcate = GenericConcat("number","number");
numberConcate(1,2);     //3 
numberConcate("a",1);   //Error: Parameter type expected: number-number
```

```
GenericConcat("string","string")("A","B");
GenericConcat("number","number")(1,2);
```